# Difference between Android Sync Manager and Work Manager

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-syncadapter

I want to know that what will be the best approach between Android sync manager and Work manager for doing background related periodic task? Is there any difference in performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WorkManager is a "new" Jetpack library that supports Android versions as old as API 14. It is much more flexible than Sync Manager as it allows to set constraints, chain workers, have one time or periodic workers.

Which one is better for your use case? it really depends from the use case. For sure WorkManager is more flexible.

You can find more information on [WorkManager's documentation](http://d.android.com/workmanager) and on this [series of blogs](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/introducing-workmanager-2083bcfc4712).